# how to empty all the registers already used, to restart the program in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers, mips32, spim

I am new to MIPS and I have an assignment for uni.
I have a program(game) in Mips, and I am trying to write a function to restart the game after finishing.
I already have my restart function but the problem is that I have to clear all the registers I've used before.
does anyone know how I can do for clearing in the fastest and easiest way?(I have 740lines of code,That's why i am asking for easiest and fastest.)

Comment: Why do you need to zero out the registers?

Comment: @ThomasJager Because when the game starts again, it contains the last used addresses which is full . so basically it can not use that address(pixel). and i need to clear everything so it can restart from zero.

Comment: The answer that's been given is very good, you should refer to that, but I don't see what's stopping you from just jumping to the beginning of the main function in your code (after popping anything pushed to the stack. I would expect that you load registers with all the needed values anyways.

Comment: If you want your code to run again, you have to re-initialize everything that you need re-initialized.  That includes global variables as well as registers, though for the registers you should not be relying on the simulator to clear them for you, but doing that yourself.  If you use code ever as a subroutine instead of a `main`, it must expect the registers to be non-zeroed and do so itself as needed.

Comment: On the other hand if you just want to clear all the registers, then you can do each one individually, e.g. `li $t0, 0`.  There's no mass-clear the registers.

Comment: I consider it a flaw that the simulators clear the registers for you in the first place -- they should put -1 or 0xdeaddead in them so no one can rely on them being cleared.  Code that fails to initialize its variables has a classic logic error called [Uninitialized Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Registers can't be "empty", they always hold some value in their 32 bits.  There is no metadata anywhere outside them that indicates which registers have / haven't been written.

You don't need to do anything special.  Non-buggy code in the rest of your program should already assume any register holds garbage (not necessarily zeros) if it hasn't written to it.  (Or done something like a system call, which would get the simulator to put a useful value in a register.)

Think of registers as being like local variables in C.  Like `int a0, a1, t0, t1;` *not* `int a0=0, a1=0`, etc.  That's why you write loops like `for(t0=5 ; t0!=0 ; t0--)`, where the first access is a write (assigning a `5` to the variable / register).  In asm that means `li $t0, 5` before the loop.  If you didn't, your loop would run some unknown number of iterations, depending on whatever previous code left in `$t0`.  (In C, it's undefined behaviour or at least an unspecified value to read an uninitialized local variable.  In practice you get some garbage from somewhere, because C compiles to asm, and in asm for real CPUs, every register and memory location always has a value.)

(In some senses, global variables are a better analogy since all code uses the same registers for different purposes at different times.  But since you don't want to read whatever garbage some previous function left in them, it makes equal sense to consider the separate life-times as separate local variables.)

---

If you did want to zero some registers, obviously you just write instructions like

```
li  $a0, 0
li  $t0, 0        # work-around for buggy code that assumes registers are zeroed
...
j  main
```